# external tool to copy data from external workbook to target workbook

Tags: excel, vba, import, copy

I have 1 external xlsm file that contains the macro code I need to perform operations for several templates. This is the actual process how I would like to have it in short:

1. 'Template' is opened by user. User clicks 'refresh' button
2. 'mytool' is opened and performs several operations in 'template'
3. after performing operations 'mytool' is closed again and templates is saved
4. user works in template with updated data.

I now want to change this tool a bit so it not only performs operations on the target workbook, but firstly, copies the needed data from another external workbook. I have been trying and searching to find code to have this done, but I am struggling with it to get it right.

1. 'Template' is opened by user. User clicks 'refresh' button
2. 'mytool' is opened and performs several operations in 'template' **including opening the raw data file and copying the data in the file to 'template'**
3. after performing operations 'mytool' is closed again and templates is saved
4. user works in template with updated data.

*edit: own solution added to question on the bottom of this question.*

I have this code to make the external tool act/work in the target workbook:

```
Sub vernieuwalles(mytemplate As String)
  
  Windows(mytemplate).Activate
```

In the target workbook, I have this code:

```
Sub vernieuwalles()
Dim myTemplate As String: myTemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim myTool As String: myTool = "refresh_base_incrementals.xlsm"
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
  Workbooks.Open GetPath & myTool
  Application.Run myTool & "!vernieuwalles", myTemplate
  
  Call Windows(myTool).Close(False)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetPath() As String
Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition
  
  GetPath = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\XLAM\"

End Function
```

I want the *tool* to open another excel file which is located in a seperate directory. This is the directory structure I use for this:

location target workbook:

`\Promo reports\test\`

this is the location for the tool:

`\promo reports\xlam\`

this is the location for the external workbook:

`\Promo reports\test\data files\`

I was already busy with adjusting existing code to have the correct location in it:

```
Sub import_data()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Workbooks.Open GetPath & fileName
fileName = Mid(mytemplate,18,Len(mytemplate) - 4



End Sub
Private Function GetPath() As String

Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition
  
  GetPath = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\test\data files\"

End Function
```

But then I got stock. I want the data from 3 sheets having copied to those some sheets (they already exist) in the target workbook.

There are 3 sheets: Food-Drug, ASW A, ASW P.

The external workbook is a data file which filename will be consequently the same as the templates name but shorts. for example:
the template name is *promo rapportage prostaat.xlsb*

the datafile name will be *prostaat.xlsb*

I want the tool to use the name of the template to get the right filename to open in the data files directory.

How can I add these operations to "mytool"?

**edit:**

I now changed the code(s) to this:
in the *target* workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Sub vernieuwalles()
Dim mytemplate As String: mytemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim myTool As String: myTool = "refresh_base_incrementals.xlsm"
Dim myData As String: myData = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 18, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
  Workbooks.Open GetPath & myTool
  Workbooks.Open GetPath2 & myData
  Application.Run myTool & "!vernieuwalles", mytemplate
  
  Call Windows(myTool).Close(False)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
Private Function GetPath() As String
Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition
  
  GetPath = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\XLAM\"

End Function
Private Function GetPath2() As String

Dim myPosition As Integer
Dim myPath As String: myPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

  myPosition = InStr(StrReverse(myPath), "\") - 1
  myPosition = Len(myPath) - myPosition
  
  GetPath2 = Mid(myPath, 1, myPosition - 1) & "\test\data files\"
  
End Function
```

And in the *external script file* (mytool):

```
Sub importdata()
Dim mytemplate As String: mytemplate = ActiveWorkbook.name
Dim myData As String: myData = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.name, 18, Len(ActiveWorkbook.name) - 4)
Dim sheetnames As Variant, i As Integer

sheetnames = Array("food-drug", "ASW A-merk", "ASW PL")

  For i = LBound(sheetnames) To UBound(sheetnames)
    With Workbooks(myData).Sheets(sheetnames(i))
      aantalrijen = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1
      .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(aantalrijen, "DO")).Copy _
        Workbooks(mytemplate).Sheets(sheetnames(i)).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End With
  Next i

End Sub
```

I tested this with a template called 'promo rapportage prostaat.xlsb' and it perfectly opens the file prostaat.xlsb and copies the data on the 3 worksheets in this file to the worksheets in the target workbook.

Comment: You don't need to *Select* or *Activate* anything. Once you can identify an object by name or location you can assign it to a variable and access any part of it for read or write. Your question lacks clarity with regard to which code is running from which location. Make it a rule that only one project's code can run at a time. Forget about activating a workbook and thereby triggering code in it that responds to the Activate event, if that's your plan. Even if you can make it work the code in the first workbook would have to continue where it left off after the intervening call is complete.

Comment: the code runs completely from 'mytool'. and are executed in the target workbook. because I have like 20 templates which work/operate the same, I wanted to have only 1 file with code/operations because otherwise I would have to change the code 20 times if something changes. Now I have to change it only once. But I noticed some part of the templates causing problems with the users and I want to solve this by importing the raw data from an external data file.

Comment: So, the code resides in a "Personal Workbook". How is it called and what does it do? If you focus on these two questions you would be better able to explain your problem. The logical flow in your above presentation isn't easily discernible. As a result I, for one, have failed to understand what you want from us. I recommend that you re-work your question. Make it shorter and more to the point.

Comment: I kept trying today and found a way that works now. perhaps not the most efficient, but it works. As far as I can see (I did not create the original script, that was done by a specialist) the windows(mytemplate).activate line was added to make sure the right window was active so the code is performed in the right file and the right filenames are used. I updated my question with what I "created" myself now.